# Change operation with C++ template

Tags: c++, class, templates, operators

This is probably a duplicate question, however I am not sure how to search it and I could not find anything yet. Suppose that I have two classes that look like:

```
class MyMatrix : public MyAbstract {
  using MatrixType = Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>;
  MatrixType A, B;
 public:
  ...
  MatrixType product() { return A * B; }
  ...
}
```

and

```
class MyDiagonal : public MyAbstract {
  using VectorType = Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 1>;
  VectorType A, B;
 public:
  ...
  VectorType product() { return A.cwiseProduct(B); }
  ...
}
```

All functions in both classes are the same, but the second class handles diagonal matrices only, so they can be stored as vectors. Is it possible to merge these two classes to one, using for example a template to choose the type of variables and the corresponding operation (matrix or componentwise multiplication)?

Comment: Do you just want to reduce code duplication, or do you really want them to be the same template class?

Comment: Hi Justin, thank you for the response. I haven't heard of CRTP before so I need to look more at this. But I just need to reduce duplication (not have to write all the functions twice with the two different products), without affecting efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP):

```
template <typename Derived>
class MyMatrixLikeThing : public MyAbstract {
public:
    void do_something() const {
        // How to access members of Derived:
        static_cast<Derived const&>(*this).A;
        static_cast<Derived const&>(*this).B;
        static_cast<Derived const&>(*this).product();
    }

    // Other functions
};

class MyMatrix : public MyMatrixLikeThing<MyMatrix> {
    friend MyMatrixLikeThing<MyMatrix>; // so that it can access private members

    using MatrixType = Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>;
    MatrixType A, B;

public:
    MatrixType product() const { return A * B; }
};

class MyDiagonal : public MyMatrixLikeThing<MyDiagonal> {
    friend MyMatrixLikeThing<MyDiagonal>; // so that it can access private members

    using VectorType = Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 1>;
    VectorType A, B;

public:
    VectorType product() const { return A.cwiseProduct(B); }
};
```